# Encode data in c# - Decode data in RoR

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, base64, encode

I am having a problem with Base64.decode64

In my xamarin app I'm encrypting the information with C#:

```
public static string Encrypt(string _stringEncrypt)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    byte[] encryted = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(_stringEncrypt);
    result = Convert.ToBase64String(encryted);
    return result;
}
```

After that,  shoot an endpoint to my api

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Global.server);
string url = string.Format("/api/login?username={0}&password={1}", Global.Encrypt(entryUserName.Text), Global.Encrypt(entryUserPass.Text));
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

My api code:

```
def login
  username = Base64.decode64(params[:username])
  userpass = Base64.decode64(params[:password])

  user_log = User.authenticate(username, userpass)
end
```

My problem is that the login is null. I do "puts the data" in the developer server, this one is correct.

Then I open rails console and I shoot the next code:

```
url = "http://www.mymy.com/api/login?username="+Base64.encode64s("myuser")+"&password="+Base64.encode64s("mypass")

data = JSON.parse(RestClient.get(url))
```

GUALAAAAAA, the login is correct.

the difference is that the encripted result data is different between C# method and Base64.encode64s de RoR

ANY IDEA THAT RECOMMEND?

pd: Sorry for my engish!

Comment: First, you are not encrypting anything, just Base64 encoding a byte array. Second, try using the UTF8 encoding to create your byte array instead of Unicode (might help, might not, worth a shot).

Comment: It is better to use the correct naming of variable and functions, using the word "encrypt*" when you mean "encode*" just causes confusion.

Comment: Based on my test, both base64 values are identical.... `Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("testUsername"))` gives me `dGVzdFVzZXJuYW1l` string.....and `Base64.encode64('testUsername');` also gives me `dGVzdFVzZXJuYW1l` :)

Comment: @Kevin Thanks Kevin, the error is Uniode, I needed UTF8. I dont saw this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Hackerman - you are using UTF8 as I suggested, he is using Unicode encoding to create the byte array he is then Base 64 encoding. Those extra 0 bytes in his origin array are his problem.